# Массив радио кнопок и клик по ним

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть форма, почему при клике по радио отрабатывает всегда первый радиобаттон?

```js
$("#radio1").click(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Получение ID формы
    var formID = 'curr';
    // Добавление решётки к имени ID
    var formNm = $('#' + formID);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'assets/codephp/currier/mappes.php',
      data: formNm.serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        // Вывод текста результата отправки
        $('#mappes').html(' ');
        $('#mappes').html(data);
      },

      error: function(jqXHR, text, error) {
        // Вывод текста ошибки отправки
        $('#message').html('Ошибка');


      }
    });
    return false;
  }, 1000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="" id="curr" name="curr">

  <input type="radio" name="idzad[]" id="radio1" value="3">
  <label for="radio1">Звёздная улица 21, 3</label>

  <input type="radio" name="idzad[]" id="radio1" value="4">
  <label for="radio1">Якуба Колоса 16, 3</label>

</form>
```

Comment: почитай про разницу идентификаторов и классов.. и почему идентификатор на странице должен быть один

Answer (score 3):

> Вы повесили клик на id, который у двух элементов
>
> id у каждого элемента должен быть уникальным

```js
$(".radio").click(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Получение ID формы
    var formID = 'curr';
    // Добавление решётки к имени ID
    var formNm = $('#' + formID);
    console.log(formNm.serialize());
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'assets/codephp/currier/mappes.php',
      data: formNm.serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        // Вывод текста результата отправки
        $('#mappes').html(' ');
        $('#mappes').html(data);
      },

      error: function(jqXHR, text, error) {
        // Вывод текста ошибки отправки
        $('#message').html('Ошибка');


      }
    });
    return false;
  }, 1000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="" id="curr" name="curr">

  <input type="radio" name="idzad[]" class="radio" value="3">
  <label for="radio1">Звёздная улица 21, 3</label>

  <input type="radio" name="idzad[]" class="radio" value="4">
  <label for="radio1">Якуба Колоса 16, 3</label>

</form>
```

Comment: вешать обработчик на `n ( .radio )`  элементов не есть хорошей практикой

Comment: Согласен, т.к. могут повторятся классы на странице.
Можно повесить, например,  $("#curr input.radio")

Answer (score 1):

Id уникален, вот он и выбирает первый попавшийся элемент с этим id.

```js
$("#radio1").click(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Получение ID формы
    var formID = 'curr';
    // Добавление решётки к имени ID
    var formNm = $('#' + formID);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'assets/codephp/currier/mappes.php',
      data: formNm.serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        // Вывод текста результата отправки
        $('#mappes').html(' ');
        $('#mappes').html(data);
      },

      error: function(jqXHR, text, error) {
        // Вывод текста ошибки отправки
        $('#message').html('Ошибка');


      }
    });
    return false;
  }, 1000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="" id="curr" name="curr">

  <input type="radio" name="idzad[]" id="radio1" value="3">
  <label for="radio1">Звёздная улица 21, 3</label>

  <input type="radio" name="idzad[]" id="radio2" value="4">
  <label for="radio2">Якуба Колоса 16, 3</label>

</form>
```

Comment: У Вас все равно будет отрабатывать только один radio button, потому что клик повешен на id первого radio